# Memory error in python: solve the equation of two dimensional fluid velocity profile

Tags: python, scipy, equation

I'm trying to solve the equation of Q(flow rate) = a(flow rate ratio).
Q(flow rate) is obtained through the flow velocity profile u(y,z) of rectangular channel.
But i have a one issue. My code cannot solve the equation with memory error.
I tried to solve the equation with 128 GB RAM.
I think the python is hard to solve the hyperbolic sin function.
So I want to get any help of solving this problem.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import *

# channel property
H = 0.00005 # m: channel height
w = 0.00002 # m: channel width
L = 0.015 # m: channel lenghth
#k = sy.symbol('k')
#y = Symbol('y')
#z = Symbol('z')

# fluid property
eta = 0.001041 # Pas: viscosity of polymer solution

# flow property
deld = Symbol('deld')

def u1():  # sample flow rate was fixed at 1, flow rate ratio 1-10 
    u1_list = []
    for i in range (1, 11):
        Q_sample = 1*(10**-9)/60 # set up the sample flow rate
        Q_total = Q_sample + Q_sample*i
        delP = (((8*eta*L)*(w+H)**2)/((w**3)*(H**3))) * Q_total
        u1_caculation = (4*(H**2)*delP)/(np.pi*eta*L)
        u1_list.append(u1_caculation)
    return u1_list

#print (u1())


def sumfunc(): # summation
    summation_all = 0
    y = Symbol('y')
    z = Symbol('z')
    for k in range (0, 3): # k개수 조정
        summation =((2*k+1)**(-3)) * ((1-(sy.cosh((2*k+1)*np.pi*y/H)/sy.cosh((2*k+1)*np.pi*w/(2*H)))) * sy.sin((2*k+1)*np.pi*z/H))
        summation_all = summation_all + summation
    return summation_all

#print (sumfunc())


def Q_sheath_func(): # obtain the definite integral
    Q_sheath_int = []
    #velocity_list = [] # check
    y = Symbol('y')
    z = Symbol('z')
    sin = sy.sin
    cosh = sy.cosh
    sinh = sy.sinh
    for i in range (0, 10):
        # Q_sheath inetgrate
        velocity = u1()[i] * sumfunc()
        #velocity_list.append(velocity)
    #return velocity_list
        sheath_integral_1 = sy.integrate(velocity, y) # y indefinite integral
        y_sheath_first = sheath_integral_1.subs(y, w/2-deld) # y enter the upper limit
        y_sheath_second = sheath_integral_1.subs(y, -w/2+deld) # y enter the under limit
        y_sheath_cal = y_sheath_first - y_sheath_second # y definite integral
        
        sheath_integral_2 = sy.integrate(y_sheath_cal, z) # y indefinite integral
        z_sheath_first = sheath_integral_2.subs(z, H) # y enter the upper limit
        z_sheath_second = sheath_integral_2.subs(z, 0) # y enter the under limit
        z_sheath_cal = z_sheath_first - z_sheath_second # y definite integral
        Q_sheath_int.append(z_sheath_cal)
    return Q_sheath_int

#print (Q_sheath_func())

def Q_total_func(): # obtain the definite integral
    Q_total_int = []
    #solution_eq = []
    #solution = []
    #velocity_list = [] # check
    y = Symbol('y')
    z = Symbol('z')
    sin = sy.sin
    cosh = sy.cosh
    sinh = sy.sinh
    for i in range (0, 10):
        # Q_total integrate
        velocity = u1()[i] * sumfunc()
        # velocity = u1()[i] * sumfunc()
        total_integral_1 = sy.integrate(velocity, y) # y indefinite integral
        y_total_first = total_integral_1.subs(y, w/2) # y enter the upper limit
        y_total_second = total_integral_1.subs(y, -w/2) # y enter the under limit
        y_total_cal = y_total_first - y_total_second # y definite integral
        
        total_integral_2 = sy.integrate(y_total_cal, z) # y indefinite integral
        z_total_first = total_integral_2.subs(z, H) # y enter the upper limit
        z_total_second = total_integral_2.subs(z, 0) # y enter the under limit
        z_total_cal = z_total_first - z_total_second # y definite integral
        Q_total_int.append(z_total_cal)
    return Q_total_int

#print (Q_total_func())

def solution_func(): # solve deld 
    solution_eq = []
    solution = []
    #velocity_list = [] # check
    y = Symbol('y')
    z = Symbol('z')
    sin = sy.sin
    cosh = sy.cosh
    sinh = sy.sinh
    for i in range (0, 10):
        # dled solution
        solution_d = (Q_sheath_func()[i] / (Q_total_func()[i] - Q_sheath_func()[i])) - (i+1)
        solution_eq.append(solution_d)
        
        solution_width = sy.solve(solution_eq[i], deld)
        solution.append(solution_width)
        
    return solution

print (solution_func())
```

Comment: what is `deld`, if it is always real (or even better always positive) then passing that as an assumption is going to assist sympy in the solution, it also means you can numerically evaluate the solution easily, also a known interval of the solution will greatly help the solver, this equation might have infinite roots in the complex domain, which is the cause of this problem, so limiting the interval of the solution will greatly help. (much like how sine has infinite real roots, sinh has infinite complex roots)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).